# Where is the "Add product" tab in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, magento-1, programmatically, place-order

Trying to add product manually for an existing customer, but the orange tab is no longer there.

[image: orange_btn]

Comment: Hello, can you be more specific , that what you want and which `orange tab` frontend or backend .

Comment: Here is one external link written by `Magento Certified guy` http://frankclark.xyz/magento2-1-programatically-create-order

Comment: The tab existed in the previous version (1.9) when i would go to "manage customers".  I would select a customer, go to "create order", then click on "add product" to access our inventory catalog.  I cannot access our inventory catalog from our "create order" page.

Comment: I think i added the correct picture ?\